# SQLite 3.24 - Counting occurrences of value grouped by id without using window functions

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, window-functions

Apologies if this has been asked, but maybe I'm not familiar with the language to ask for what I want, and I looked through dozens of other questions but don't seem to be finding what works.

I'm working on a tool for a trading card game, a deck is a list of cards, I have a table mapping `deckId` to `cardId`

Given the example (rowid not shown)

```
deckId| cardId
-----------
1  | 321
1  | 50
1  | 100
1  | 125
2  | 321
2  | 50
2  | 99
2  | 87
3  | 50
3  | 12
3  | 5
3  | 47
4  | 999
4  | 998
4  | 997
4  | 996
```

What I am trying to query is for each deck, how many cards does it have that appear in more than 1 deck.

```
deckId  |  count(cardId)
--------------------
1  | 2 // 321 and 50 appear in both deckId=1 and deckId=2
2  | 2 // 321 and 50 appear in both deckId=1 and deckId=2
3  | 1 // 50 appears in deckId=2 and deckId=3
4  | 0 // none of the cards in deckId=4 appear in any other decks
```

I've tried

```
SELECT deckId, COUNT(cardId)
FROM table
GROUP BY deckId
```

but it just gives me (because each deck has 4 cards):

```
deckId  | count(cardId)
-----------------------
1 | 4
2 | 4
3 | 4
4 | 4
```

So how do I query for each deck, how many "common" cards does it have?
(window functions were suggested, but i'm forced to use SQLite version 3.24 before window functions are implemented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select 
    deckId,
    sum(case when cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from (
    select deckId, count(*) over(partition by cardId) cnt
    from mytable 
) t
group by deckId
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6ea7c489b940e0f354006aeb6f18ed6e)**:

```
deckId | cnt
:----- | --:
1      |   2
2      |   2
3      |   1
4      |   0
```

---

In versions of SQLite that do not support window functions, you can emulate the window count with a subquery:

```
select 
    deckId,
    sum(case when cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from (
    select 
        deckId, 
        (select count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.cardId = t.cardId) cnt
    from mytable t 
) t
group by deckId
```

Comment: Hmm, i might need to be more specific in the question because SQLiteStudio is giving me a syntax error with that query. While that might answer the question as posed, how migh ti do it with SQLite (the sdk i'm using in my tool to date)

Comment: @BrianSterling You're probably using an outdated version of sqlite that pre-dates window functions.

Comment: Responding to my own comment, it appears that the DB Fiddle link IS set to SQLite, but it's set to version 3.27 and I think the dll i'm using with Unity is limited to 3.24, but i'll se if I can find a newer version

Comment: It appears window functions weren't added until 3.25, so i'll have to either update my dll's or find an older solution

Comment: @BrianSterling: I edited my answer with a solution that does not use window functions.

Comment: I tried to use the SQLite dll's utilizing System.Data.SQLite, but found that there wasn't the support for Android / iOS builds I needed, so I went back to Mono.Data.SQLite, which didn't support the WITH clause, so now the subquery approach in the second half of this response is what works so I've marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that doesn't use window functions:

```
WITH counted AS
  (SELECT deckId,
          (SELECT count(*)
           FROM decks AS d2
           WHERE d.cardId = d2.cardId) AS cnt
   FROM decks AS d)
SELECT deckId, sum(cnt > 1) AS Duplicates
FROM counted
GROUP BY deckId
ORDER BY deckId;
```

which produces for your sample table

```
deckId      Duplicates
----------  ----------
1           2
2           2
3           1
4           0
```

(You'll want separate indexes on the `deckId` and `cardId` columns for best performance.)